# Clean up Parse database

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-dashboard

My Parse database is getting filled up with a ton of records for stuff that I don't need to keep around, such as 80k entries in the `_PushStatus` class. If I select "delete class" from the Parse dashboard to get rid of those records, will Parse recreate that class the next time it needs to log a push notification?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete all rows instead of deleting the class? I believe whether or not the class automatically gets recreated depends on if client class creation is allowed, but may be mistaken in this case.

Comment: Ah, I completely missed that option. Do you know if the `_PushStatus` class is used for anything besides logging the success/failure of the push? Could deleting those records have any unintended consequences?

Comment: That I am unaware of. It doesn't even show in my database. It may be something specific to your push adapter?